# Nested System.import calls with Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm developing a single page app that has several routes, and some small portion of those routes draw widgets to the screen. Each route has a lazy loaded React component that's responsible for drawing the content.

The widgets npm package I'm using is quite large, so I don't want to bundle it in the main application, but I also don't want to include in every single dynamic bundle for the routes that need it.

To this end, in Webpack 1.x I was able to do the following for my routes:

```
function loadComponentForRouteA() {
  return function (location, callback) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      require('widget-package');

      require.ensure([], (require) => {
        callback(null, require('path/To/Route/Component/A'));
      }, "nameOfRouteBundleA");

    }, "nameOfWidgetPackageBundle");
  }
}

function loadComponentForRouteB() {
  return function (location, callback) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      require('widget-package');

      require.ensure([], (require) => {
        callback(null, require('path/To/Route/Component/B'));
      }, "nameOfRouteBundleB");

    }, "nameOfWidgetPackageBundle");
  }
}
```

This would nicely generate 3 webpack bundle files:

- nameOfWidgetPackageBundle.js
- nameOfRouteBundleA.js
- nameOfRouteBundleB.js

And then when I hit /route/A in the app, it'd load two js files sequentially: nameOfWidgetPackageBundle.js and then nameOfRouteBundleA.js

Then, if I subsequently navigated to /routeB, it'd load two js files sequentially: nameOfWidgetPackageBundle.js and then nameOfRouteBundleA.js, but crucially, nameOfWidgetPackageBundle.js would be fetched from the browser cache...

After changing to Webpack 2.x syntax, I have the following for my routes:

```
function loadComponentForRouteA() {
  System.import('widget-package')
    .then(widgetPackage => {
      System.import('path/To/Route/Component/A')
        .then(Component => {
          callback(null, Component);
        });
    });
}

function loadComponentForRouteB() {
  System.import('widget-package')
    .then(widgetPackage => {
      System.import('path/To/Route/Component/B')
        .then(Component => {
          callback(null, Component);
        });
    });
}
```

This generates several chunkFiles (annoyingly System.import in Webpack 2 no longer lets you name the chunk files, but I'll use the same bundle naming style as require.ensure from Webpack 1 for the purposes of the example):

- nameOfWidgetPackageBundleA.js
- nameOfWidgetPackageBundleB.js
- nameOfRouteBundleA.js
- nameOfRouteBundleB.js

So basically duplicate bundles are created for the widget package. The two files have identical file sizes, and almost identical content, but navigating between the different routes will now require re-downloading the widget package each time it's used.

My question here is, does anyone know a way to force Webpack 2 System.import to behave more like Webpack 1 require.ensure, and not generated duplicate bundles?

EDIT - I tried using the following webpack plugins to fix the issue:

new CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'widget-package', async: true, children: true, minChunks: 1}) (added widget-package as an entry)

new DedupePlugin()

new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin({ minSizeReduce: 1.5, moveToParents: false, entryChunkMultiplicator: 10 })

The only one of these that had any effect was the AggressiveMergingPlugin. It solved the duplicate widget-package bundle problem, but also merged ALL of my dynamic bundles which defeats the whole purpose, since there is now only one dynamic bundle...

Comment: not sure this will solve it but try adding in [DedupePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin) to webpack plugin config

`new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),`

You could also look into [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin). See example 3. Move common modules into the parent chunk

Comment: I edited the issue to list some of the plugins I tried to use to solve the issue, so far without any luck :-(

Comment: Any chance of a example repo with your setup?